# Creating binding in codebehind

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have this type of code in aspx but wish to generate it in code behind.  What would be the equivalent?

```
<uc1:editformcontrol ID="EditFormControl1" runat="server" CategoryID=' <%#Bind("CategoryID") %>' />
```

The question pertains mainly to the binding

Comment: show data source please.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say without knowing your data model. What kind of data source are you using?  You could try adding this line to the Page_Load method:

```
int categoryId;
categoryId = WHEREEVER YOU'RE STORING THIS VALUE...
EditFormControl1.CategoryID = categoryId;
```

Comment: Maybe the answer is so simple I don't think of it but this will just set the value.  <%#Bind... will do two way binding

Comment: I see - you're looking for two way binding?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you override the OnDataBound event on your control and bind the data there.

[See here one example.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.onitemdatabound.aspx)